# Sharing physical examples of the Normal distrbution from real life for fun

Tags: normal-distribution

**I wanted to make this question more fun than science.**

I am not asking for the statistical help, but I rather wonder if you can share your examples. If you think it is off-topic, feel to close immediately.

I have recently helped my folks with restoration of a target stump used for knife throwing. This stump was getting knife hits for about 5-7 years, and when it splitted I couldn't stand the chance to take photos of the wood destruction pattern. Just in accordance with the "many random factors combination", the density of the hits has become Gaussian-like shaped!

**It maybe suitable in an educationl context, I think.**

[image: one half]

[image: second half]

[image: whole thing]

Comment: +1 for creativity nonetheless!

Comment: Thanks. The question is, however broad, can you find material suggestive examples of the natural phenomena that support the math by just naked eye which can be helpful in class?

Comment: Vaguely symmetric and bell shaped is not the same thing as "normal". Many things are more-or-less symmetric and unimodal. (Why isn't that an example of a beta-distribution, say?)

Comment: Well, good point. This looks noisy and not symmetrical. This is because, in particular, when you throw a heavy object it tends to go a little below the middle line, in contrast to a classic shooting problem. Another aspect is that the wood has been getting damage from a great variety of sources; I personally trained with 10 different shapes and weight of projectiles. It should be approaching Normal because each hit is a combination of lots of random factors, but people aim at the center, this is how training goes, it very much resembles the shooting example, but is more noisy physical process.